# Is deep learning the only way to detect humans in a picture?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, segmentation, deep-learning

I'm looking for a way to detect humans in a picture. For instance, regarding the picture below, I'd like to coarsely determine how many people are in the scene. I must be able to detect both standing and sitting people. I do not mind not detecting people located behind a physical object (such as the glass in the bus picture).

[image]

AFAIK, such a problem can rather easily be solved by training deep neural networks. However, my coworkers would like me to also implement a detection technique based on general image processing techniques. I've spent several days looking for techniques designed by researchers but I couldn't find anything else than saliency-based techniques (which may be fine, but I'd like to test several techniques based on old-fashioned image processing).

I have strong constraints on the nature of images, for instance luminosity: whether they've been taken during the day or at night, the pictures will have very different characteristics (e.g. image contrast can strongly vary).

**Long story short, I'd like to know if there's indeed some existing segmentation technique for which it'd be interesting giving a shot, given the fact that the information carried by the images vary a lot?**

Answer (score 2):

One of the popular feature descriptors used for human detection is HOG - [Histogram of Oriented Gradients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients). Usually you would train a classifier for recognizing human vs non-human, and then you would implement a sliding window technique. HOG has implementations in most of the scientific libraries in the Python community, for example in skimage there is an example [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_hog.html), which I am copying here because a link could always become broken:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.feature import hog
from skimage import data, exposure


image = data.astronaut()

fd, hog_image = hog(image, orientations=8, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16),
                    cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualize=True, multichannel=True)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)

ax1.axis('off')
ax1.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax1.set_title('Input image')

# Rescale histogram for better display
hog_image_rescaled = exposure.rescale_intensity(hog_image, in_range=(0, 10))

ax2.axis('off')
ax2.imshow(hog_image_rescaled, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax2.set_title('Histogram of Oriented Gradients')
plt.show()
```